# How to identify redundant libraries from Makefile? Is there any tool to analyse the library usage?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, shared-libraries

How to identify redundant libraries from Makefile?  Is there any tool to analyse the library usage?

For a c++ program , built using make , I want to find which libraries are no longer used by program but still linked by make utility.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Linux then possibly you should use ldd --unused:

```
$ ldd --help
Usage: ldd [OPTION]... FILE...
  -u, --unused            print unused direct dependencies
```

This is an example:

```
$ ldd -u ./a.out                                      
Unused direct dependencies:

    /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/cl11203/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
    /usr/local/CC/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    /lib64/libm.so.6
    /usr/local/CC/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
```